# How to display a message even when user is logged out?

Tags: 7

I'm using Drupal 7, i want to display a message `drupal_set_message`, when i click on a button for example.

When i'm logged it works well, but for this same button (or page) if i'm not logged in, it doesn't display any message.

This is my case : i've created a mobile application that used a backoffice. this backoffice is built using drupal. i've created a page "reset password" user can click on "reset password" from the mobile app, an email sent with a link to my custom page : reset_pwd

this page contains inputs to reset new password :

```
$items['reset_psw'] = array(
'title' => '',
    'description' => '',
    'access arguments' => array('administer reset_psw'),
    'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('reset_mdp_formulaire'),
);
return $items;
```

the form to reset password :

```
function reset_mdp_formulaire ($form, &$form_state){

$form = array();

$form['confirm_pass'] = array(
    '#type' => 'password_confirm',       
);

$form['valider'] = array(
    '#value' => t('valider'),
    '#type' => 'submit',           
);
return $form;
 }
```

the function submit :

```
function reset_mdp_formulaire_submit ($form, &$form_state){
$new_pass = $form_state['values']['confirm_pass'];
dsm("error");
if(strlen($new_pass) < 8){

    drupal_set_message(t('Password must be 8 characters at least.'), 'error'); <== not shown when logged out
    return;
}
 }
```

Just want to check if new password is less than 8 characters, and display error message

Thank you all.

Comment: It's the validation handler that should show such errors. `drupal_set_message()` works for anonymous users too, so the error is somewhere else.

Comment: As side note, the string passed to `t()` needs to be in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the return statement at the end of your submit or even replacing it with a drupal_goto('reset_psw').

There are lots of similar questions on google and S.O., you could have a look.

UPDATE

You should use the validate handler for such a case, this simple example should get you going https://www.drupal.org/node/717740